# Como acrescentar porcentagem a um valor em PHP?

Tags: php, porcentagem

Estou tentando acrescentar uma porcentagem do valor nele mesmo, porém não consegui fazer.

```
   <?php

   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://broker.negociecoins.com.br/api/v3/btcbrl/ticker"));
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data->sell);
  echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Eu tenho esse JSON que me retorna um valor e gostaria de acrescentar por exemplo +30% nesse valor antes de exibi-lo, mas de todas formas que tentei não dá certo, alguém tem uma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$valor *= (1+$percentual/100);

$data->sell *= (1+30/100); //30% de acréscimo
```

Ou dessa forma.

```
$valor_acrescido = (($data->sell*30)/100)+$data->sell;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, você é o cara.

Answer (score -1):

## Porcentagem

```
$valor_acrescido = (($data->sell*30)/100)+$data->sell;
```

Comment: Qual a diferença da sua resposta à outra?